# how to call id of cmultifileupload in yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

in Cmultiplefileupload widget i want to call my own js function and want to track the id of the widget id

```
   <script>
function inc_id(x)
{
    alert(x);

}   
  </script>

$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
        'name' => 'LeadRecommendations[docs_name][]',
        'id'=>'LeadRecommendations_docs_name',
        'model'=>$test,
        'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png|pdf|doc|docx|odt|txt|xlsx|xls|csv|zip', // useful for verifying files
        //'duplicate' => 'Duplicate!', // useful, i think
        'denied' => 'Invalid file type', // useful, i think
        'remove'=>'[x]',
         'options'=>array(


        'afterFileSelect'=>'function(e, v, m){ inc_id(this.id) }',

 ),
```

but it gives the result undefined how could i get he id of this widget in my function

Comment: Isn't the 3rd argument (m) the Multifile instance? You should be able to do m.id

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the first argument provides the required id as e.id